# Injection causes WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: jboss, ejb, cdi, java-ee-8, ejb-3.2

I have a java EE web application in which a particular injection causes following error:

> WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type GenericDAO with qualifiers @Default

**MyBean**

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean extends CustomBean<Entity> {
...
}
```

**CustomBean**

```
public class CustomBean<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private GenericDAO<T> genericDAO;
}
```

**GenericDAO**

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
...
}
```

The issue appears only if a beans.xml is defined in the application. Deleting this, solves also the issue. In my case beans.xml is needed.  Also when removing the `GenericDAO<T> genericDAO;` injection from the CustomBean, the error does not appear anymore. Also the rest of my injection in other classes, seem to work without any issue.

I've tried to solve that by creating an interface of GenericDAO and inject the interface instead. Also tried to with several anotations like @Local , @Dependent etc but i stumble upon different errors every time.

Comment: What does the implementation of `GenericDAO` look like? CDI can't inject an abstract instance without knowing the implementation.

Comment: GenericDAO contains methods persistence methods common for most of my entities. As i mentioned though, i  tried extracting an interface out of GenericDAO and injecting this instead, without much luck

Comment: CDI has to know the implementation for the `GenericDAO` whether it's abstract or an interface. If you've got several types that extend or implement `GenericDAO` you need to tell CDI which one you want injected. CDI can't really know or make the guess.

Comment: But isn't that information passed with the parameter in the injection on  private GenericDAO<T> genericDAO; Unless i understood something else. Yes, i have many other DAO that extend the GenericDAO. E.g. : public class SampleDAO extends GenericDAO<Sample>

Comment: I'm not a CDI expert, however I don't think it considers generic types when looking for a match. I'm not really sure how that could work TBH.